# Segfault after repeated reallocs

Tags: c++

EDIT: Thanks a lot for the answers. That's right, I will try using vectors instead.

I have a program where I dynamically allocate memory.

The class has an attribute which is an array of structs (**) and also an array of pointers (*) which point to each element of the array of structs, so I make 2 Mallocs. The struct is called "context".

The realloc works fine and doesn't return NULL, but as soon as I have more than 2 elements, the program will give me a segfault when trying to save a value in an element of the array. How can I prevent this segfault?

```
int my_class::method(uint32_t struct_element)
{
    int i= this->numofcontexts;
    if(this->local_context_array == NULL)
        // That means it is empty and we have to make our first malloc
    {
        this->local_context_array = (context_t**) malloc(sizeof(context_t*));
        *(this->local_context_array) = (context_t*) malloc(sizeof(context_t));
        i++;
        std::cout << "\n1 Malloc was made of size " << sizeof(context_t)<<"\n";
    }
    else
        // Array is not empty and we have to use realloc
    {
        this->local_context_array = (context_t**) realloc(this->local_context_array, (i+1)*sizeof(context_t*));
        *(this->local_context_array) = (context_t*) realloc(*(this->local_context_array), (i+1)*(sizeof(context_t)));
        std::cout << "\n1 Realloc was made of size " << (i+1)*(sizeof(context_t)) <<"\n";
        i++;
        std::cout << "\nWe now have " << i <<" elements\n";
        // As soon as the array is bigger than 2 elements, this gives segmentation fault:
        //(this->local_context_array[i-1])->struct_element = struct_element;

     }
```

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`/`realloc` in C++? You should probably be using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: On which system, with which compiler and compilation flags are you developping? Please edit your question to improve it. Perhaps use a memory leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`); also avoid your own `malloc` in C++ code.

Comment: As for your problem, never assign to the pointer you're reallocating, remember that if `realloc` fails it will return `NULL` and make you loose the original pointer.

Comment: You don't update `numofcontexts` anywhere. And your code is both slower than the equivalent using a `vector` and more broken.

Comment: You should avoid C-style casts.  You should use `std::size_t` for `numofcontexts`.  You should check your multiplications (in passing a number of bytes to `std::realloc`) for overflow.  Or, alternately, use `std::vector`, which does all these things for you.

Comment: And what is the purpose of the second realloc exactly ?

Comment: since allocating memory is an expensive operation you normally try to avoid that as much as possible, in your case you call it every time you want to add a struct which makes the code really slow. Instead allocate say 100 structs and then once those are used up allocate 100 more. Also skip `i` and use `numofcontexts` directly.

Comment: Did you reassign the `i`value to `numofcontexts`? Seems to me you are only incrementing it locally, but we don't have the full code.

Answer (score 0):

From the code posted and the symptoms you describe, it seems you do not do this at the end:

```
this->numofcontexts = i;
```

If this is true, then every time you call this method, it will find numofcontexts == 0 and local_context_array not NULL, so it will move to your else clause, when it will reallocate the array to i+1 (always 1).

First call will succeed, second call will also succeed with array size of 1 element, and if you try to assign to elements over [0] at this point, you may get a segfault. The reason you might not get a segfault at [1] is usually related to some other variable occupying the space and being trashed but which does not always generate a segfault immediately.